No GPU acceleration in Wayland with dual GPU system (Intel and Nvidia)
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 with an Nvidia RTX 3060 and Intel UHD 770. Both work fine in X11, but in Wayland I cannot get hardware acceleration to work.
My lshw -c video output:
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA104 [GeForce RTX 3060]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:175 memory:42000000-42ffffff memory:60000000-6fffffff memory:70000000-71ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:43000000-4307ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Raptor Lake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 770]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:174 memory:41000000-41ffffff memory:50000000-5fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:44000000-4affffff
  *-graphics
       product: simpledrmdrmfb
       physical id: 2
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1024,768

Kernel version 6.8.0-31-generic Nvidia driver version 550.
I believe it has something to do with the simpledrmdrmfb since it creates a new dri interface in /dev/dri/by-path linked to card0.
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8 May 31 07:52 pci-0000:00:02.0-card -> ../card1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 May 31 07:52 pci-0000:00:02.0-render -> ../renderD128
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8 May 31 07:52 pci-0000:01:00.0-card -> ../card2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 May 31 07:52 pci-0000:01:00.0-render -> ../renderD129
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8 May 31 07:52 platform-simple-framebuffer.0-card -> ../card0

From syslog it seems the simpledrm causes issues with mutter:
2024-05-31T07:52:14.178626+02:00 user systemd[5217]: Started app-gnome-at\x2dspi\x2ddbus\x2dbus-5652.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
2024-05-31T07:52:14.178639+02:00 user systemd[5217]: Reached target gnome-session-manager.target - GNOME Session Manager is ready.
2024-05-31T07:52:14.178952+02:00 user systemd[5217]: Starting org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service - GNOME Shell on Wayland...
2024-05-31T07:52:14.178964+02:00 user systemd[5217]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service - GNOME Shell on X11 was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionEnvironment=XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11).                                                                             
2024-05-31T07:52:14.202273+02:00 user gnome-shell[5666]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 46.0) as a Wayland display server
2024-05-31T07:52:14.231458+02:00 user gnome-shell[5666]: Device '/dev/dri/card2' prefers shadow buffer
2024-05-31T07:52:14.380456+02:00 user gnome-shell[5666]: Added device '/dev/dri/card2' (nvidia-drm) using atomic mode setting.
2024-05-31T07:52:14.566037+02:00 user gnome-shell[5666]: Device '/dev/dri/card1' prefers shadow buffer
2024-05-31T07:52:14.566495+02:00 user gnome-shell[5666]: Added device '/dev/dri/card1' (i915) using atomic mode setting.
2024-05-31T07:52:14.568049+02:00 user gnome-shell[5666]: MESA-LOADER: failed to open simpledrm: /usr/lib/dri/simpledrm_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
2024-05-31T07:52:14.588141+02:00 user gnome-shell[5666]: Added device '/dev/dri/card0' (simpledrm) using atomic mode setting.
2024-05-31T07:52:14.589261+02:00 user gnome-shell[5666]: Created gbm renderer for '/dev/dri/card2'
2024-05-31T07:52:14.589759+02:00 user gnome-shell[5666]: Created gbm renderer for '/dev/dri/card1'
2024-05-31T07:52:14.589792+02:00 user gnome-shell[5666]: Failed to initialize accelerated iGPU/dGPU framebuffer sharing: Not hardware accelerated
2024-05-31T07:52:14.589821+02:00 user gnome-shell[5666]: Created gbm renderer for '/dev/dri/card0'
2024-05-31T07:52:14.589849+02:00 user gnome-shell[5666]: Boot VGA GPU /dev/dri/card2 selected as primary
2024-05-31T07:52:14.590220+02:00 user gnome-shell[5666]: Obtained a high priority EGL context 
2024-05-31T07:52:14.590899+02:00 user gnome-shell[5666]: Obtained a high priority EGL context

So how can I disable this device? Is there a package I should uninstall or something I should blacklist? I don't care about power usage I just want to use my Nvidia always.
Also running eglgears_wayland I get:
libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
Thanks

I was able to disable the simpledrm driver with this snippet in the grub kernel line: initcall_blacklist=simpledrm_platform_driver_init.
This did not fix my problem, however. I uninstalled all Nvidia-related drivers and reinstalled them, but at version 535. 545 didn't build for my kernel.
Now, I have accelerated graphics on Nvidia in Wayland.
I've since removed the kernel line, which is still working fine. The simpledrm issue was just a red herring, it seems.
